# How to typeset a nine-line equation

Tags: equations

[image]

What structure creates an equation that looks closest to the one above? It seems `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` doesn't break lines by default let alone make it look this pretty.

Comment: The lines are jumping back and forth ... pretty?

Comment: I would use `equation`  with the terms on the right in an `aligned` that would also align the operators, the image you show looks rather odd with no alignment to the terms

Comment: @Johannes_B that was my first thought as well but actually I think the indentation matches the `[` nesting so it's not completely unreasonable

Comment: `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b] ... \end{aligned}\end{equation}` should do it, but better looking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting an image it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Giving people working code to start from makes it much  easier for people to help you and, hence, much more likely that some one will.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Use a nested `equation`/`aligned[b]` environment along with `&\quad` (twice) and `&\qquad`  (six times) statements to perform the horizontal aligning in rows 2 thru 9.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{8} % just for this example
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\frac{X_{12}}{i}
&=      \Bigl[\Bigl\{\Bigl[(a_{k_{+}}\cdots\Bigr]  \\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{u}{v}\cdots\Bigr] \\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{m}{n}\cdots\Bigr]\Bigr\}\Bigr] \\
&\quad -\Bigl[\Bigl\{\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{a_{k_{+}}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdots\Bigr]\\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{x}{z}\cdots\Bigr] \\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{p}{q}\cdots\Bigr]\Bigr\}\Bigr] \\
&\quad +\Bigl\{\Bigl[\Bigl(a_{k_{+}}\cdots\Bigr]\\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{f}{g}\cdots\Bigr] \\
&\qquad+\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{k}{l}\cdots\Bigr]\Bigr\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i think that the equation would be easier to understand if op omitted excessive square brackets before curly ones.

Comment: @Zarko - I fully agree! However, since I will freely admit to having no clue what the nine-line equation stands for, I will have to leave it to the OP to omit any unnecessary round parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces. :-)